# Violet UML editor , Maven, Mac

Tags: java, git, maven

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLUgt.png)Hello I am new to maven,
Like given in developer's guide I downloaded Violet UML editor source code from GitHub and tried to **mvn clean install** from from command line in my Mac laptop but it throws the following error :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project violetproduct-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.horstmann.violet:violetproduct-web:war:2.5.3: The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.horstmann.violet:violet-framework:jar:2.5.3, com.horstmann.violet:violetplugin-classdiagram:jar:2.5.3: Failure to find com.horstmann.violet:violet-framework:jar:2.5.3 in http://violet.sourceforge.net/maven2/repo/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of violet.repo has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I tried **mvn clean site** also still shows the same error
Please help me out. Having assignment submission on Friday

[screenshot of GitHub link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLUgt.png)

Comment: It doesn't look like those artifacts are in the repo `http://violet.sourceforge.net/maven2/repo/`. If you go to the URL you can navigate around, and I only see snapshot versions, not the released 2.5.3 versions that you're trying to fetch. I'm not familiar with Violet UML, but perhaps there is a different repository you need to list in your pom.xml for those dependencies?

Comment: @avojak, I have posted the screenshot the link from which I downloaded the source code. https://github.com/violetumleditor/violetumleditor . I used the download zip option which is shown in the pop up. Does that allow me to access the released version of the software or is there any other option?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you actually need to build it from the source code? Or can you just download the editor from the link in the README?

Comment: As a pat of the assignment I am supposed to install it in local IDE from source code

Comment: I used this link to run it in STS through svn link https://github.com/violetumleditor/violetumleditor.git following the guidelines in http://alexdp.free.fr/violetumleditor/page.php?id=en:developerguide . Since it is for an older version it doesn't work for the current one also shows lots of compilation and build error. If you need the error in STS I can give u that

Comment: If cloning the GitHub project, then running `mvn clean package` ([as mentioned in the README](https://github.com/violetumleditor/violetumleditor)) fails because of missing dependencies, then you'll need to log an issue to the project since it looks like the repo is missing some artifacts.

Comment: I have lodged a ticket in the website. Hope they resolve it soon. Thank you very much for your help. Yet pls suggest some alternative if you have any.